# No Module name 'encodings', deploying Django on a Linux Apache2

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache2, mod-wsgi

I try to deploy my Django Project on a Debian OS. I use the Anaconda 3 environment for the project that I've made.

Here is the configuration of my Apache2

```
Alias /static /home/mydef/django_project/static
<Directory /home/mydef/django_project/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/mydef/django_project/django_project>
    <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/mydef/django_project/django_project/wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess django_project python-path=/home/mydef/django_project python-home=/home/mydef/venv
WSGIProcessGroup django_project
```

Then Reload the Apache 2 (already enable my own apache2 conf file)
Then I try to visit it localhost. But it didn't show any response (loading only). Then I check the error log then I see this error.

```
 Current thread 0x00007f4d175f1040 (most recent call first):
 [Thu Jan 02 05:58:14.571867 2020] [core:notice] [pid 9737:tid 139969081315392] AH00051: child pid 10145 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings
```

I also try Searching but still not solved

Comment: I've seen this before when the version of Python in your `python-path` of your `WSGIDaemonProcess` doesn't match the Python version `mod_wsgi` was compiled with.

Comment: but I already installed the ` libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 ` on my system